# Updating rules in kie container

Tags: kie

I am new to KIE. I just want to know how to update (or modify) the rule (WHEN condition) deployed on a KIE container. Suppose the current condition is that amount > 1000, and if I want that condition to be changed into amount > 2000 programmatically, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are working with the KIE execution server. You would change that condition in the DRL/DSL/GDRL/etc. file in the KIE workbench and after validation and compilation of the project, you would deploy the project on the execution server again....I am not sure if I am missing the point here....what is exactly the problem?